# MAC OSX, which version of MySQL should I download?

Tags: mysql, macos

I have a MAC OSX 10.6, intel 64 bit,

I'm looking at the mySQL download options at  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx

There are no download options for 10.6, do you think the 10.5 downloads below will work?
Mac OS X 10.5 (x86)
Mac OS X 10.5 (x86_64)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed and use x86_64 on a snow leopard macbook pro.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, but when I untar the file, I do not see any .configure file there.  Did you?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://www.mmisoftware.co.uk/weblog/2009/08/29/mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-and-mysql/) a fresh install of the version you mentioned above should work.

Best wishes,
Fabian